# abort() has been called when running insertion sort function

Tags: c++, insertion-sort, abort

I'm trying to sort string vector using insertion sort, but when I run the following program it gives me an error saying "abort() has been called" and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
void InsertionSort(vector<string> *Strings,int SIZE) {

    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {

        string temp = Strings->at(i);
        int j = i - 1;
        while (Strings->at(j) > temp  && j >= 0) {

            Strings->at(j+1) = Strings->at(j);
            j--;
        }
        Strings->at(j + 1) = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: In while condition `j >= 0` should be tested as first, otherwise you can call `at(-1)`.

Comment: Unrelated, `SIZE` makes little sense in the context. a `vector` (assuming you're using `std::vector<std::string>`) already has a `size()` member, so unless you're trying to sort only a sub-sequence of the vector that argument is redundant.  Also, this should ideally be done with iterators.